# How to add a background image to the body of a html email?

Tags: css, html-email, document-body

How can I add a background image to the body of a html email? Pasted below are my `CSS` styles:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

    /* Linked Styles */
    body { 
        background:#000; 
        padding:0 !important; 
        margin:0 !important; 
        display:block !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; 
        background-image:url(images/t1_free_bg.jpg); background- 
        repeat:no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position:0  
     }

     a { 
         color:#e85853; 
         text-decoration:none 
     }

     p { 
         padding:0 !important; 
         margin:0 !important 
     } 

     img { 
         -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */ 
     }

     .mcnPreviewText { 
        display: none !important; 
     }


    /* Mobile styles */
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        u + .body .gwfw { width:100% !important; width:100vw !important; }

        .m-shell { width: 100% !important; min-width: 100% !important; }

        .m-center { text-align: center !important; }
        .center { margin: 0 auto !important; }

        .td { width: 100% !important; min-width: 100% !important; }
        .h2 { font-size: 35px !important; line-height: 40px !important; }
        .nav { font-size: 12px !important; line-height: 22px !important; padding: 10px !important; }

        .m-br-15 { height: 15px !important; }
        .p0-15-30 { padding: 0px 15px 30px 15px !important; }
        .p0-20-30 { padding: 0px 20px 30px 20px !important; }
        .p30-0 { padding: 30px 0px !important; }
        .p30-20 { padding: 30px 20px !important; }
        .pb30 { padding-bottom: 30px !important; }
        .p10 { padding: 10px !important; }

        .m-td,
        .m-hide { display: none !important; width: 0 !important; height: 0 !important; font-size: 0 !important; line-height: 0 !important; min-height: 0 !important; }

        .m-block { display: block !important; }

        .fluid-img img { width: 100% !important; max-width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; }

        .column,
        .column-dir,
        .column-top,
        .column-bottom,
        .column-dir-top { float: left !important; width: 100% !important; display: block !important; }

        .content-spacing { width: 15px !important; }
    }
</style>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I feel like I am almost there with the code. Right now the image is pixelated/blurry and it doesn't cover the entire page in certain browsers. The image is currently sized at 1366x1024.

Comment: can you add your HTML code? Also can you consider making a code sandbox so we can see what is going on?

Comment: I don't know if this will affect your current problem, but you might want to make it a more responsive design by changing from absolute "px" units to relative "em" or "%" units.  E.g.  change "15px" to "1em".

Comment: This will not work for anyone using Outlook 2007-2019.

Answer (score -1):

I had an issue like this recently. In my case, I didn't specify the image path properly. Make sure your path (relative or absolute) is correct.